# How to make specific checkbox items bold (not all) via CSS?

Tags: html, css

I have a CSS coding challenge for everyone here...
I have searched google and looked at multiple options, but cannot figure this one out.
Is also worth mentioning that I'm not a developer, but I understand the basics of how to implement CSS.

I have a section of code that contains check boxes,
I need to make only specific checkbox items bold (not all of the items) via CSS...

Under normal circumstances, the CSS code for this would be: font-weight: bold;
in the right class or ID, however, in my case, I'm using a third party platform with predefined, css classes for each of the code sessions, in the case of the checkboxes section, the CSS class for this is called: .formFieldLabel

So the CSS code section would like so:

```
.formFieldLabel {
padding-bottom: 2px;
}
```

Below is the html code section for the checkboxes:

---

```html
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div class="" style="overflow: hidden">
          <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="1" class="">
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td width="20" align="left">
                  <input type="checkbox" name="Field 1" id="form_0006_fld_2-0" value="First Choice">
                </td>
                <td width="*" align="left" style="padding-top: 3px; padding-right: 10px">
                  <label for="form_0006_fld_2-0" class="formFieldLabel">First Choice</label>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div class="" style="overflow: hidden">
          <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="1" class="">
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td width="20" align="left">
                  <input type="checkbox" name="Field 1" id="form_0006_fld_2-1" value="Second Choice">
                </td>
                <td width="*" align="left" style="padding-top: 3px; padding-right: 10px">
                  <label for="form_0006_fld_2-1" class="formFieldLabel">Second Choice</label>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div class="" style="overflow: hidden">
          <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="1" class="">
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td width="20" align="left">
                  <input type="checkbox" name="Field 1" id="form_0006_fld_2-2" value="Third Choice">
                </td>
                <td width="*" align="left" style="padding-top: 3px; padding-right: 10px">
                  <label for="form_0006_fld_2-2" class="formFieldLabel">Third Choice</label>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

---

Resuming, the CSS code to make such item bold will need to go inside the following CSS code section:

```
.formFieldLabel {
padding-bottom: 2px;
}
```

Can anyone please help me implement this solution?

Comment: SO is not the place to post _coding challenges_.

Comment: @MelanciaUK SO is exactly the place, if OP has tried that on his own and failed.

Comment: @Banana No. SO is a Q&A website. It's about asking for help with coding, not asking people to code it for you.

Comment: What exactly are the `specific checkbox items`? And is it the labels that you need them to be bold?

Comment: @MelanciaUK i think you missed 50% of my comment

Comment: @Banana The only thing missing here is a real question. We don't even know what the OP meant with _specific checkbox items_.

Comment: Need to ask this: What means OP?

Comment: @MelanciaUK It's not a *coding challange* where you can win prices. The OP means that the coders should feel challenged.

Comment: @Joanes `Original Poster` I may be wrong though.

Comment: @HerrSerker I got it. But so far the challenge here is to know what the OP actually wants.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [attribute selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#attribute-selectors) like this.

```
    <style>
    .formFieldLabel[for=form_0006_fld_2-0] {
    font-weight: bold;
    }
    </style>
```

But you have to know the id of checkbox to do this.

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no way to add an id to the checkboxes :(
You can see the generate code above.

Comment: If checkboxes IDs are always the same after reloading the page, it means that `for` attribute of labels are always the same, too. And it means, that you can style them this way. In my example the first label will be bold.

Comment: Actually, you have cracked this one.

I had to add the following code:

}
 .formFieldLabel[for=form_0006_fld_2-0] {
    font-weight: bold;
    }

 .formFieldLabel[for=form_0006_fld_2-2] {
    font-weight: bold;
    }

the first and last item are now bold. 

Thank you.

Comment: Actually, it's a little underused CSS feature. People sometimes suppose that it's not implemented in IE or something like that, but it's been there since IE7 and works in every modern browser! (http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sel2)

Answer (score 4):

You could use `:nth-child()` selector in css to select the checkbox you want.

So maybe something like this to select the second checkbox:
`tr:nth-child(2) table input { }`

Not sure it the above css works but, you can use `:nth-child()` to select the `<tr>` you want from the parent table then from there you can select the input box in the child table.

Comment: This seems like a good idea. If that's the thing the OP wants.

Comment: If that's not what OP is asking then I completely misunderstood the question.

Comment: That's the problem. I didn't see any question by the OP

Comment: Do you mean something like so? 
.formFieldLabel {
padding-bottom: 2px;
tr:nth-child(2)
font-weight: bold;
}

meaning the 2nd checkbox text would be bold but not the others.

Comment: @Silva it would be something like `tr:nth-child(2) table .formFieldLabel { padding-bottom: 2px;}`

Comment: @Silva sorry, forgot the font-weight `tr:nth-child(2) table .formFieldLabel { padding-bottom: 2px; font-weight:bold;}`

Answer (score 0):

or just add a second css class

```
class="formFieldLabel boldLabel"
```